# Variations in ldots

Tags: fonts, math-mode, punctuation, latin-modern

Here is my code:

```
 \documentclass{article}
 %\usepackage{unicode-math}
 %\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
 \begin{document}
 The letters $a, \ldots, z$ are used.
 \end{document}
```

It produces this output, when typesetting with XeLatex:
[image]

If I uncomment the second line, I get:
[image]

If I uncomment the second and third lines, I get:
[image]

My questions are:

(1) Are these the expected/correct results, or does it look like my TeX or font installation is somehow messed up?

(2) I suppose the third result is a consequence of the design of the ellipsis character in the Latin Modern fonts. Is this design as intended, or is it regarded as a bug? I personally don't like how it looks, but that's just a matter of taste, I guess.

Comment: In my opinion this is *not* the expected/correct result; one may find the usual dots too spaced out, but at least there should be the possibility to choose from different dot spacing. However, I get the same result whether or not Latin Modern Math is loaded.

Comment: > **I get the same result whether or not Latin Modern Math is loaded**. So, in other words, you get the same result for my cases #2 and #3?  So, that means there is something wrong with my configuration. Or, it's different from yours, anyway.

Answer (score 7):

`unicode-math` changes `\mathellipsis` to mean

```
\mathinner{\unicodeellipsis}
```

where `\unicodeellipsis` just prints the character `…` in whatever is the current font (Latin Modern Math, if you don't set another one).

This *does* make sense, because, for instance, one can then copy-paste the dots and get a single character rather than three periods.

However I don't like at all this kind of Unicode police that forces a using glyphs based on the preferences of whoever created the font. Right or wrong, spaced out dots *are* used and the authors of Latin Modern Math should acknowledge it. Adding a stylistic variant to an OpenType font is not difficult.

If you want to revert to the spaced out dots (but using three periods), add

```
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \renewcommand\mathellipsis{\mathinner{\ldotp\ldotp\ldotp}}%
}
```

after loading `unicode-math`.

Comment: Sounds like Unicode should have a "math-ellipsis" character, maybe, with wider spacing. I don't expect that will happen anytime soon. But defining my own mathellipsis command isn't too bad, and I can space the dots however I like. I guess that's what I'll do.

Comment: The authors of Latin Modern were just following the Unicode standard, I suppose. That's why they didn't create a widely-spaced ellipsis glyph.